# Split a column into multiple columns based on comma (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I'm creating a new table and carrying over several fields from a previous table. One of the fields is "Address" that needs to be split into several columns based on comma in the new table.

i.e current column

```
      Clientid         Address
      1                123 E 123th st, APT 4L
      2                17 E16th st, APT 3B
```

newly created columns:

```
       Clientid                address1                 address2
       1                       123 E123th st            APT 4L
       2                       17 E 16th st             APT 3B
```

My question is is this even possible without hardcoding? Since I can't tell how many characters away the comma is for each individual record I'm assuming I'll need to come up with some sort of loop to check the condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()`, probably with `trim()`:

```
select trim(regexp_substr(address, '[^,]+', 1)),
       trim(regexp_substr(address, '[^,]+', 1, 2))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a7ec3e19ef216e751f60848849401b9) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some basic SUBSTR & INSTR function -

```
SELECT Clientid,
       SUBSTR(Address, 1, INSTR(Address, ',') - 1) address1,
       SUBSTR(Address, INSTR(Address, ',') + 1, LENGTH(Address)) address2
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```